# Can the Android phone use the windows DirectX library?

Tags: android, directx, android-ndk

I have some functions which draws the game screen using the Direct X library in Windows.
So, I am trying to use the functions in Android phone using the ndk.
But I have some problems. Dose the Android phone which use the Java recognize the Direct X functions? If it is possible, then I must have some controls about it?
I want your help...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Android (and iOS as well) doesn't support DirectX but OpenGL ES. Check out [3D with OpenGL](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html) on the Android developer site.

Answer (score 3):

Android uses a  linux kernel, not a windows one. So I'd suspect no.

Answer (score 1):

No, because Android is based on Linux Kernel, whch supports OpenGL.

Answer (score 1):

OpenGL is pretty similar to DirectX it doesn't take too much effort to convert between the 2.  Failing that you could probably find the implementation in the Wine source code on how they handle DirectX calls and pass them to OpenGL.